# Printing both name and value of a generic variable in C

Tags: c, generics, pragma

I want to combine two `fprintf()` calls at the same line into one call of a function, e.g.,  `fprintf_together_with_variable_name(FILE* fpheader, FILE* fpresult, char* f_str,...)`.

My MWE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define var2str(e) (#e)
int main() {
        FILE* fpresult = fopen("result.txt", "a");
        FILE* fpheader = fopen("header.txt", "w");
        char* mtx = "web-Google.mtx";
        double time = 3.452;
        int flop = 7684;
        fprintf(fpresult, "%s\t", mtx);         fprintf(fpheader, "%s\t", var2str(mtx));
        fprintf(fpresult, "%g\t", time);        fprintf(fpheader, "%s\t", var2str(time));
        fprintf(fpresult, "%d\t", flop);        fprintf(fpheader, "%s\t", var2str(flop));

        fprintf(fpresult, "\n");                fprintf(fpheader, "\n");
        fclose(fpresult);
        fclose(fpheader);
        return 0;
}
```

It easy to write one function for each type `int`, `double`, and `char*` or to pass name of the variable as a string; however it will be great to have one generic function that takes only the variable and  handles all types.

Comment: Yeah, it will certainly be great.

Comment: You might be able to do it with C11's _Generic and a varargs macro.

Answer (score 3):

A bit ugly, but have you tried

```
#define var2str(e) e,#e
fprintf(fpresult, "%s\t%s\t", var2str(mtx));
```

or even uglier :P

```
#define var2str(e) " %s\t", e,#e
fprintf(fpresult, "%s\t"var2str(mtx));
```

This should work I think.

Comment: Macros is what the GoogleTest library uses to achieve a similar result, so I'd say there's no shame in doing that.

Comment: I wonder if you could further generalize the format string, maybe something using typeof(e) == int ? "%d" : ...

Comment: @Leeor that could be done, at the very least the 2nd %s can be appended, since that is always the same.